Do any philosophers describe drama as fundamental to, or the essence of, the human condition?
Whenever I contemplate philosophy or science the convention that I call "name dropping" always evokes my experience of interpersonal drama. Here is my favorite example of name dropping:

When I am ten, eleven, and twelve years old my teacher of Reading Comprehension, Ms. Wexler, instructs the students to decode the meaning of words, phrases, and sentences in context.

When I encode the meaning into words (write the sentence) it evokes my memories of drama. I doubt the reader knows the person Ms. Wexler, but I infer the sentence will evoke the dramatic roles of student and teacher, and if the reader has no experience of drama then there is no means to decode the message that I intend to convey.
Here is another example of name dropping:

To study motion Galileo rolled balls down a smooth incline plane, across a horizontal table, and allowed the ball to fall to the ground in his laboratory, comparing the rolling and falling motion to the motion of a pendulum.

Often I contemplate physical quantities such as position, displacement, elapsed time, velocity, acceleration, and (parabolic) trajectory without evoking this story of Galileo's motion experiment. But it seems that I have learned about these quantities exclusively in the context of drama including stories about scientists like Galileo.
Here is another example of what I call name dropping:

Baruch Spinoza describes an affect as a feeling of desire, pleasure, or pain accompanied by an idea of its cause. He further describes desire as appetite accompanied by consciousness thereof. He describes general sources of cause as the self, other humans, nature, and an abstract God.

I have not read and studied philosophy as a discipline. Spinoza is the only philosopher in my awareness who takes drama seriously. Galileo imitated the ancient Greek pattern of the dialogue to publish his ideas. Besides using the literary device of the dialogue, are there philosophers who attempt to describe the essence of human life as patterns of drama, and who integrate core patterns of drama into their description of philosophy?
Comment - I am aware of Object theories in psychoanalysis. This is an effort to describe drama in which the ego interacts with objects of its experience such as the mother's breast, the mother's role, the father's role, etc. But this is cast in the domain of behavioral pathology rather than in the more philosophical realm of what is fundamental or essential to a human experience.

David Loy wrote a book called, "The World Is Made Of Stories", I highly recommend it. You can learn a lot about Nonduality through his books.

I wonder if Yuval Noah Harari, author of "Sapiens", read "The World is Made Of Stories"? He says of sapiens, "Storytelling is our superpower." I think it is true that God gave us dominion over the earth in the Biblical sense. Even if one is atheist it would be true except replace God with some other supernatural source of cause. The atheist just prefers to tell oneself a different type of story. In my case the philosophical analysis of stories began with high school courses in literature, sociology, and psychology. Continued with college courses in literature and interpretation of the Bible.

I'd say Galileo and Ms. Wexler are different. The latter is story (or drama) building. The former is more likely to be Proof by Authority. Have you noticed how most physicist's voice changes when they say "Einstein"?

Søren Kierkegaard starting with his 1841 master's thesis On the Concept of Irony with Continual Reference to Socrates.

@SystemTheory The idea of humans as storytellers is a common theme among anthropologists. It was the subject of a recent episode of "The History of the Future" on PBS.

@Rushi - I think after Newton made his discoveries he said, "If I have seen farther than other men it is only because I was standing on the shoulders of giants." He probably had Galileo and Kepler in mind, among so many others (I call them The Ancient Scholars). Then I think after Einstein made his discoveries he quoted Newton about standing on the shoulders of giants. I think he had Maxwell and Newton in mind and so many others. I think we "consult" our own authority to evaluate the truth-value of statements made by Ms. Wexler or Galileo but we can imitate and expand the methods of Galileo.

@MauroALLEGRANZA SEP article on Kierkegaard:  https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/kierkegaard/#KierAnalHumaExisDespSociCritAnxi. "We attempt to ground our identities in “worldly distinctions” such as riches and fame or define ourselves by our devotion to abstractions that have the potential to become idols, such as nation, race or class. On Kierkegaard’s view, only when one is defined by a commitment to what is absolute and infinite (God) can one be freed from the constricting labels and conformist roles that society attempts to impose on all of us." I call it my effort to "transcend drama".

As long as people don't treat us the way Galileo and Giordano Bruno were.

None of these quotes are examples of 'name dropping'.  It's really unclear what you think that term means.

@JimmyJames - Upon reflection I realize name dropping has a distinct meaning of trying to impress others by mentioning actual relations to famous individuals. I am not aware of a similar term with the meaning I intend. What I mean is we use the name of a human figure to evoke drama and we automatically infer or consciously assume there is some shared meaning with others in our drama. I may try to create my own thesaurus on the subject because I don't think one exists. In patent law the person who drafts claims to an invention defines terms as a lexicographer which evokes semantic ambiguity.

When I read the topic first, I went straight to SEP to look for resources on Drama. As in the theatrical form. Then I read OP's question more closely and am now aware that they are asking about a completely different thing - drama as in "to make a drama out of something", or some kind of emotional excitement or agitation. I'll let my answer stand for anyone who finds the question randomly and is indeed looking for the aforementioned meaning of the word.
That said, the concept of carthasis could almost be related to OP's question, as - while being a theatrical term in the first place - could be taken as using negative emotions ("drama" in the modern sense) and their eventual resolution for the betterment of the audience.
Here are some references from SEP and Wikipedia, from whence you can see whether they list more sources in case you want to dig deeper:

Theater
Greek Tragedy
Catharsis
Plato's Aesthetics
Plato's Myths
Plato on Rhetoric and Poetry
Schopenhauer's Aesthetics
And for good measure: Japanese Aesthetics

You might glean more readings by entering proper search terms in the SEP search directly ("theater", "drama", and so on and forth).

A couple more links, for more "forgotten knowledge": Greek Tragedy, Catharsis

I have taken them into my list, @JulioDiEgidio. Carthasis is a great concept here, maybe linking the theatrical stuff to OP's question at least a bit.

Physics can be pretty dramatic. I keep hoping it has an "eventual resolution for the betterment of the audience."

Dang, aren't you being overly dramatic now, @ScottRowe? :D

Drama - is something to remember.
I like the description of human life as a character in the Puppet Show.
You actually have some free will when you are young. You have a chance to show that you are capable of the leading role, or, like the majority of us, you play in the background.
After your role is assigned, the rest of your life tries to push you along to your destiny.
At this point, your free choice is mostly: success or failure.
And we tend to remember the drama well because it helped us to get on a path of our destiny.

Yes, emotions cause strong memories and associations. People who had lobotomies or other conditions that suppress emotional salience have trouble making decisions, even trivial ones, and they don't learn as easily. Emotions exist for very good reasons! That doesn't mean we need to act on felt emotions though, or avoid emotions.
